# A character string to numeric conversion failed while using syntax like 'OPE' =?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, teradata

I try to run this query using Spring JDBC Template

```
  public static String FIND_CNC_OPE_GRAPPE_BY_FCT_ID = 
        "SELECT "
                    +"EXPO.COD_NAT_XPN "
                    +", EXPO.IDF_TEC_XPN "
                    +", EXPO.IDF_FCT_XPN_RIS "
                    +", EXPO.DAT_PRM_IPE_LC_CEC  "
        +"FROM  T_CCA_EXPO EXPO "
        +"WHERE "
        + " 'OPE' = ? ";
```

for this i use this java code :

```
  import java.sql.Connection;
  import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
  import java.sql.ResultSet;
  import java.sql.SQLException;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.List;

  import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
  import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
  import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
  import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

  import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

  @Repository
  @Slf4j
  public class ContractGrappeRepository implements ContractGrappeInterfaceRepository {

       static String query = GrappeQueryConstant.FIND_CNC_OPE_GRAPPE_BY_FCT_ID;

       @Autowired
       private JdbcTemplate baseJDBCTemplate;

       private Connection dbConnection;

       private PreparedStatement statement = null;

       private ResultSet dealResultSet;

       @Override
       public ResultSet findGrappeByDealFctID() {

       try {
          dbConnection = baseJDBCTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();
          statement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(query);
          statement.setString(1,"AKA");
          dealResultSet = statement.executeQuery();
       } catch (SQLException e) {
          throw new RestructNumberException("Exception while fetching contracts",e);
       }

       return null; // TO MODIFY
   }

 }
```

When the compilator arrive to this line dbConnection.prepareStatement(query); i got this error message ;

```
   java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 16.00.00.24] [Error 3535] [SQLState 22003] A character string failed conversion to a numeric value.
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDatabaseSQLException(ErrorFactory.java:309)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.ReceiveInitSubState.action(ReceiveInitSubState.java:103)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementReceiveState.subStateMachine(StatementReceiveState.java:311)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementReceiveState.action(StatementReceiveState.java:200)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementController.runBody(StatementController.java:137)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementController.run(StatementController.java:128)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDStatement.executeStatement(TDStatement.java:389)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDStatement.prepareRequest(TDStatement.java:576)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDPreparedStatement.<init>(TDPreparedStatement.java:128)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdk6.JDK6_SQL_PreparedStatement.<init>(JDK6_SQL_PreparedStatement.java:30)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdk6.JDK6_SQL_Connection.constructPreparedStatement(JDK6_SQL_Connection.java:82)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDSession.prepareStatement(TDSession.java:1330)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDSession.prepareStatement(TDSession.java:1374)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDSession.prepareStatement(TDSession.java:1360)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.ManagerConnectionBase.prepareStatement(ManagerConnectionBase.java:294)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

When i run my query on Terdata sql assistant, i don't have any error.
but when i change in my query the where clause

```
    +"WHERE "
    + " 'OPE' = ? ";
```

to

```
    +"WHERE "
    + " 'OPE' = EXP.COD_NAT_XPN ";
```

I don't have any errors,

Why java don't accept this syntax **'OPE' = ?**

I am using Spring boot **1.5.9.RELEASE**

Teradata version       **16.00.00.24**

Comment: Are you trying to pass a column as a variable? And always compare that to the string `'OPE'`?

Comment: You can't keep `statement.setString(1,"AKA");` if you remove the question mark.

Comment: Depending on your version of SQL Assistant, the connection method, and option settings, SQLA may be doing simple text substitution prior to passing the query to the driver (effectively "dynamic SQL"). Bound parameters, on the other hand, can only be used to pass values, not change the tokens (e.g. column names) used in the query.

Comment: so i can't use this syntaxe in my query @Fred ?

Comment: @Andre No i try to check a variable value not the column name as variable

Comment: @devgianlu of corse, i // comment it, and i run

Comment: If you want to pass a string value to compare, the syntax is fine. It will either return all rows or no rows depending on what you pass. But it seems unlikely that's what you want. If you want to change which column's value is being compared to the fixed string 'OPE', you need to do string replacement, e.g. as @JoopEggen suggests

Comment: i want to compare with string parameter, not with a column

Comment: i'll have **where 'some string'= 'some string'**

Answer (score 0):

Change statement.setString(1,"AKA") to setInt

**Edit:**
at

```
statement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(query);
```

you are getting error because of following rule [link](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/GVKfXcemJFkTJh_89R34UQ/EdEtDim_bFUi227nLtva0A) where TeraData is trying to compile your SQL query.

For your issue I found solution [here](https://downloads.teradata.com/forum/connectivity/sqlstate-22003-a-character-string-failed-conversion-to-a-numeric-value#comment-19026). What you should do is change query as below:

```
" 'OPE' = cast(? as number) ";
```

Comment: i got new error message [Error 3784] [SQLState 42000] The number of digits specified must be between 1 and 38. when i use this one " 'OPE' = cast(? as number(60)) ";, the probleme was different, java don't accept the syntaxe of 'charsequence' = ?param

Comment: Why you have used 60? Can we use digit between 1 and 38?

Comment: i got the first error when i put 38 instead 60 [TeraJDBC 16.00.00.24] [Error 3535] [SQLState 22003] A character string failed conversion to a numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

Putting JDBC objects in `ContractGrappeRepository`'s fields is dangerous; they must be closed, and every instance must not be shared.

```
   try (Connection dbConnection = baseJDBCTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();
          Prepared statement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(query)) {
      statement.setString(1,"AKA");
      try (ResultSet dealResultSet = statement.executeQuery()) {
          while (dealResultSet.next()) {
              ...
          }
          return ...
      }
   } catch (SQLException e) {
      throw new RestructNumberException("Exception while fetching contracts",e);
   }
```

There is a conceptual error: `?` is placeholder for a value, the result being

```
'OPE' = 'AKA'               ***WRONG***
```

So you need for a column comparison concatenate/String.format the SQL string:

```
     statement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(query.replace("?", "AKA"));
```

Comment: 'OPE' = 'AKA'  also was not accepted, i tested it now !

Comment: Do a clean build, debug/log the value of `query`.

Comment: SELECT EXPO.COD_NAT_XPN , EXPO.IDF_TEC_XPN , EXPO.IDF_FCT_XPN_RIS , EXPO.DAT_PRM_IPE_LC_CEC  FROM T_CCA_EXPO EXPO WHERE ('OPE'='AKKA')

Comment: If AKA (or AKKA) is a column name then SQL syntax requires either no quotes or quotation marks (double quotes) " ". Putting the value in apostrophes (single quotes)  ' ' indicates a string literal. And what do you mean by "not accepted". If you received a syntax error, post that. If you received unexpected results (namely, no rows) then state that.

Comment: No AKA is not a column, it's a simple String, and as i said, when i try to run this sample query, i got error A character string failed conversion to a numeric value. my query is too long , and i have many OR statement, but the probleme is with 'some string' = 'some string'